# Percorrer valor de um array de uma função php

Tags: php, array, funções

Tenho essa função, gostaria de percorrer os valores dela separadamente mas travo aqui e não to conseguindo raciocinar direito pra fazer um foreach por exemplo.

```html
<?php
function numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois)
{
return array ($zero, $um, $dois);
}
$zero = 9; $um=8;$dois =7;
$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois);
foreach ($variavel as $key) {
echo $key[0];

}
?>
```

RESOLUÇÃO GRAÇAS AO AMIGO AI EM BAIXO E A TODOS QUE COLABORARAM. MUITO OBRIGADO.

```html
<?php 

function numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois) {
return array (
'numero0'=>$zero,
'numero1' =>$um,
'numero2' => $dois); 
} 
$zero = 9; $um=8;$dois =7; 
$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois); 
echo $variavel['numero0'];

?>
```

Comment: Não entendi, qual é a finalidade do código?

Comment: É possível `foreach(numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois) as $item) echo $item .'<br>';` mas não é a melhor forma ...

Comment: Não seria melhor fazer tipo: "$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois);" E depois fazer um foreach($variavel as $item). ?

Comment: faço coro ao @rray percorrer o array pra quê ?

Comment: Até aí ok, o que eu não estou conseguindo fazer é pegar apenas um item específico, tipo, quero só o numero 9, não estou conseguindo.
$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois);
foreach ($variavel as $key) {
 echo $key[0];
 
}

Comment: Vê se isso te ajuda: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chunk-split.php

Comment: vc precisa explicar melhor qual é a sua dúvida, esse código não faz muito sentido. vc pode pegar um elemento de um array especificando o indice ou chave, a sintaxe é `$variavel[0]` ou `$variavel['nome']`

Comment: Editei o código pra terem uma idéia do que quero. Ou sejam ao invés de imprimir todos os valores da função, imprime um só.

Comment: aquele `$key[0]` esqueça, deixe apenas `$key`

Comment: mas ai retorna 987 quero só o 9, ou seja,por mais que retorne 3 valores diferentes, quero apenas um específico.

Comment: Se vc quer um item em especifico basta colocar o indice na chamada como dito no outro [comentario](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127828/percorrer-valor-de-um-array-de-uma-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-php#comment266539_127828), os indices começam com zero, ou seja vc tem tres elementos no total mas contagem é de zero a dois.

Comment: entaum, seria melhor vc usar um **for** simples, algo tipo:`for ($i = 0;$<count($variavel);$i++){if $variavel[$i] == 9 break;/*...*/}`
dai voce teria maior controle sobre o loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito, mas parece que você quer adicionar os valores através da função e então chamar um específico. Você pode estar fazendo da seguinte maneira:

```
function numeros_pequenos()
{
    return func_get_args(); // retorna todos os parâmetros passados
}

// variáveis
$zero = 9;
$um = 8;
$dois = 7;

$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois);

echo $variavel[0]; // 9

// ou

echo numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois)[0]; // 9
```

O código não faz muito sentido pois você poderia estar apenas adicionando os valores dentro do array, porém tentei responder a sua pergunta.

```
$variavel = array(9, 8, 7);
echo $variavel[0]; // 9
// ou
$variavel = array(
    "zero" => 9,
    "um" => 8,
    "dois" => 7
);
echo $variavel["zero"]; // 9
```

Comment: Ae garoto, isso mesmo, Valew.

<?php
function numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois)
{
    return array ('numero0'=>$zero, 'numero1' =>$um, 'numero2' => $dois);
}
$zero = 9; $um=8;$dois =7;
$variavel = numeros_pequenos($zero, $um, $dois);

 echo $variavel['numero0'];

?>